# Swift AVFoundation subclassing AVAsset

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to subclass an AVAsset.
This is my code:

```
class TestAsset: AVAsset{


}
```

Simple...
But the (url:URL) constructor always returns an empty AVAsset:

```
   let t = TestAsset(url: url!) //--> Empty asset
   let a = AVAsset(url: url!) //--> Valid asset
```

[image]

Anyone has faced this before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you're meant to subclass `AVAsset` or any other apple SDK really. No citations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Subclass from AVURLAsset